# How to override csproj.user for msbuild invocation?

Tags: msbuild

My colleagues and I have user specific settings in csproj.user files. They are not checked into the repository. I would like for the build server to use its own set of csproj.user files, overriding certain properties, leaving the "base" project configuration at a decent developer default. But from the looks of it there is no such option in the [msbuild command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022) for doing that.

Is there really no way, other than copy csproj.user-files to where it'll be picked up by subsequent msbuild invocations?

---

While writing I realize I'm too much of a prude about these things and should just copy as a step prior build. Still posting in case someone knows a better way, for instance a way that does not modify the source tree.

Comment: If it's really only about the build server, why not pass the necessary MSBuild properties via the command line?

Comment: @mu88 I can, but only for the project passed on command line, not the projects it depends upon. Right? Should've mentioned that detail. Slipped my mind.

Comment: I'd expect that running `msbuild MySolution.sln /p:MyProperty=MyValue` should be applied to all solution projects, but honestly, I haven't tested it.

Comment: @mu88 Haha, oh dear, haven't tested it either. I'll be back on how it goes.

Comment: @mu88 Confirmed, property settings spread to dependent libraries. Will formulate an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Passing properties to the MSBuild command line overrides properties in the solution, including dependent projects. Here omitting debug information in build server, otherwise generated for release build to improve profiling:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:DebugType=none ...
```

This does not work should I want different properties for different projects. Building projects individually should work nicely though.

Finally, passing arguments on command line can get messy, so to get a more "settings file"-like experience one may instead use [`@file` arguments and MSBuild response files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-response-files?view=vs-2022).